# What does hidden_layer = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(input_layer) do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I saw the following in [a guide to text classification](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/a-comprehensive-guide-to-understand-and-implement-text-classification-in-python/):

```
hidden_layer = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(input_layer)
```

What does the `(input_layer)` mean?

The context is:

```
def create_model_architecture(input_size):

    # create input layer 
    input_layer = layers.Input((input_size, ), sparse=True)
    
    # create hidden layer
    hidden_layer = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(input_layer)
    
    # create output layer
    output_layer = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(hidden_layer)

    classifier = models.Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = output_layer)
    classifier.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy')
    return classifier
```

Also - is this a sequential model?

Comment: you need to define the input layer, so when you are compiling the model with `models.Model()` you would be able to specify it. no, it used functional API.

Comment: @SoheilStar What does functional API mean in this context?

Comment: Please use a wonderful piece of technology called "search engine": https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

Comment: And this exact question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 0):

See input layer is nothing but how many neurons or nodes you want for input. Suppose I have 3 features in my dataset then I'll have 3 neurons in input layer. And yes it's sequential model.

Comment: I think I'm confused by the syntax - why are there two sets of parentheses - ()() - after layers.Dense?

Comment: can you please specify line number

Comment: can you please specify line number. Edit:- As you can see line before layers.Dense() in second parentheses we specify the layer before it.

Comment: Why is this syntax usage not mentioned in [this guide on Keras](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/)? How would I use `model.add()` to create a model that does the same thing?

Comment: Yes you can . .

Comment: In your case you are using a function to do so.Always there are quite someways you can do the same work

Comment: @Pearl Because you cannot do the same with a Sequential model, the Functional API is meant to create graph like models, not sequential ones.